# WKWebView content size insue

Tags: swift, webview, wkwebview

When I load the webview page there is a problem that it does not show a part of the bottom, but if you zoom in on the screen, it only solves the problem from below only that the content of the webview stays on top of the iphone time.

I already tried something related to scale to fit but I was not successful. What can be done?

[Cutting the chat input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uws4M.jpg)

[issue top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sCCD.jpg)

Comment: I tried uiwebview and the issue didn't happen, but more slow than wkwebview

Comment: post code for easy understanding